# Can't Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Minimum Runtime 14.0.24123

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to install some Visual Studio Build Tools as part of NodeJS installation, but I keep getting this error when installing vcredist140-x86:

https://i.postimg.cc/s27fbQwX/microsof-visual-c-2015-error2.jpg

I have download `vc_redist.x86`, and when I try to install it this happens:

https://i.postimg.cc/FzQL2Xyt/microsof-visual-c-2015-error.jpg

When I hit cancel this is the error message I get:

> Error 1714. The older version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.24123 cannot be removed. Contact your technical support group.

Comment: Have you uninstalled all previous versions?  Choco repository in question is clearly out of date

Comment: Your errors are confusing, it’s attempting to reconfigure VC++ 2015, but your attempting to install VS2017 build tools

Comment: All Microsoft Visual C++ previous versions? If so, no I haven't. Should I?

Comment: Since you can reinstall them, if you actually need them, uninstalling the versions you don’t need is a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the troubleshooter given in the Microsoft website:
[Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d)

Uninstall the problematic packages using this tool and then reinstall them using the installer downloadable from the Microsoft website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).